# Error C2084 "already has body" should compile?

Tags: c++, inheritance, compilation

I am getting the following error messages on compile:

```
mathsphere.cpp(10): error C2084: function 'MathSphere::MathSphere(const Vec3f &,const float &,Shader *)' 

already has a body mathsphere.h(17) : see previous definition of '{ctor}'

mathsphere.cpp(10): error C2512: 'VisualObject' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

My code is as follows:

**MathSphere.cpp**

```
#include "MathSphere.h"

MathSphere::MathSphere(const Vec3f &c, const float &r, Shader* shadName) {
    radius = r;
    radiusSquared = (r * r);
}
```

**MathSphere.h**

```
#ifndef MathSphere_h
#define MathSphere_h

#include "Vec3.h"
#include "VisualObject.h"

class MathSphere : public VisualObject {
public:
    Vec3f center;
    float radius, radiusSquared;
    Vec3f surfaceColor, emissionColor;

    Vec3f getNormal(const Vec3f &pHit) const;
    bool intersect(const Vec3f &rayOrigin, const Vec3f &rayDir, float &t0, float &t1) const;
    MathSphere(const Vec3f &c, const float &r, Shader* shadName) : VisualObject(c, shadName){}
};

#endif
```

**VisualObject.cpp**

```
    #include "VisualObject.h"

VisualObject::VisualObject(const Vec3f &pos, Shader* shaderName) {
    shader = shaderName;
}

Shader* VisualObject::getShader() {
    return shader;
}
```

**VisualObject.h**

```
#ifndef VisualObject_h
#define VisualObject_h

#include "Object.h"

class VisualObject : public Object {
public:
    Shader * shader;

    Shader* getShader();
    VisualObject(const Vec3f &pos, Shader* shaderName) : Object(pos) {}
    ~VisualObject();
    virtual bool intersect(const Vec3f &rayOrigin, const Vec3f &rayDir, float &t0, float &t1) const;
    virtual Vec3f getNormal(const Vec3f &pHit) const;

};

#endif
```

Comment: Note: for some reasons this problem may have been judged too simple by some and the question despite being clear is on the verge of being closed; if it happens drop me a comment and I'll vote to re-open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, there are declarations and definitions:

- declarations are about introducing a name and some minimal information
- definitions are about defining exactly what goes beyond the name.

Declarations can be repeated (as long as they are always identical) however definitions should in general appear only once. If multiple definitions are provided, then which one would the compiler pick?

---

So, with this bit of background:

```
// MathSphere.h
    MathSphere(const Vec3f &c, const float &r, Shader* shadName):
        VisualObject(c, shadName){}

// MathSphere.cpp
MathSphere::MathSphere(const Vec3f &c, const float &r, Shader* shadName)
{
    radius = r;
    radiusSquared = (r * r);
}
```

Those are both definitions!

You have two solutions:

- a single definition, directly in the ".h" (it's okay if you do it in the class body)
- a declaration in the ".h" and a definition in the ".cpp"

Since the latter is more current, here how it works:

```
// MathSphere.h
    MathSphere(const Vec3f &c, const float &r, Shader* shadName);

// MathSphere.cpp
MathSphere::MathSphere(const Vec3f &c, const float &r, Shader* shadName):
    VisualObject(c, shadName)
{
    radius = r;
    radiusSquared = (r * r);
}
```

Although, for bonus points, you should initialize the attributes in the initializer list of the constructor:

```
MathSphere::MathSphere(const Vec3f &c, const float &r, Shader* shadName):
    VisualObject(c, shadName), radius(r), radiusSquared(r*r)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With that line in your `.h` you gave a body to your constructor.

```
MathSphere(const Vec3f &c, const float &r, Shader* shadName) : VisualObject(c, shadName){}
                                                                                        ^^
```

So either merge the two in your `.h` file or in the source file.

That should also remove the second error in the process, because in your header you actually gave arguments to the `VisualObject` constructor, but not in the source file, so the default one is assumed, and as you don't have any, it spits an error.

Comment: Hi JBL, thanks for your speedy answer. Can you elaborate a little more please? Perhaps with the corrected line of code - this has been bugging me for a bit now and Im pretty new to C++. Many Thanks!